# find the size of a JSON string before submitting it to a Azure Queue

Tags: c#, json.net

I am creating a JSON string to pass to a Azure message queue, but it cannot be larger than 64k

I am wanting to check the size before submitting it.

Here is the code that is creating it, using Newtonsoft

```
//add list of stops to StopsList class object
        StopsList stops = new StopsList() { LOBstops = stopsList };
        // Serialize using Newtonsoft.Json
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stops);

        //Insert it into the queue for processing
        insertQueueMessage(messageToInsert: jsonString, queueName: queueToUse);
```

Comment: You can measure the `jsonString` size using answer in linked duplicate

Comment: yes it does....sorry for the lack or research on this question.  Thank you.